# Why do we need to call Service layer using Interface instead of direct service class from controller in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When spring was introduced its advice to use an interface between different layers like Controller,Service,DAO instead of directly calling them using actual class reference.

In new age of Spring 5.x and Spring Boot 2.x do we need to still use interface between Controller and Service class. In my case I am developing a REST application with single GET method which call DB and do some business logic. So In my service I have only one method in this case still I do need to use ServiceInterface to call my actual ServiceImpl? what is best practice and is there any specific advantage of using ServiceInterface in this scenario?

Below is Sample code without ServiceInterface

```
public class MyTestController{

 private MyTestServiceImpl myTestServiceImpl;

public MyTestController(MyTestServiceImpl myTestServiceImpl){
      this.myTestServiceImpl = myTestServiceImpl;
}

@GetMapping("/test")
public String getTestString(){
     myTestServiceImpl.getTestString();
}
}


@Service
public class MyTestServiceImpl(){

 private MyTestRepository myTestRepository;

//constructor

//Service method impl
}
```

Comment: The reason is because of the dependency inversion principle (the D in SOLID design principles). If your question is, should I always do this even in a simple application? I would say no. These principles are meant to help you write maintainable software. If that is not what you are going for, or if the software is so simple that it would actually be in the way. Dont do it.

Comment: @p.streef Yes My question is should I need to use it always. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In very small applications, it doesn't really matter, because it is still very easy to keep track of all the classes and what classes do what. In a large scale enterprise application it can quickly become a cluttered mess. For example, if you have a rest endpoint/controller that has 100 methods, and it in turn calls 50 methods in your DAO. If you at some point decide to change the DAO methods, you will now have to change all 100 methods in the controller/endpoint. Whereas if you have a service layer in between to bridge the DAO and rest controller you only have to change the service methods.

Another point as @p.streef has mentioned is the seperation of classes and their functions. You can have a modular application wherein the service layer handles all the business logic and rules, the DAO is only responsible for database operations and the controller's only job is to send and receive data. The S in S.O.L.I.D stands for Single responsibility principle, so instead of the service layer is supposed to handle only receiving and transmitting data, and not business logic.

However, if you are building a very very small application then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Appreciate your input my main question is when should we need to use Interface between Controller and ServiceImpl and when shouldn't. If we look all Spring documentation each serviceImpl example will implement an interface even service implements single method. When spring was introduced it uses CGLIB to create proxy object for creating dependent beans of defined dependencies so defining a dependent bean using interface reference make it easier this what my understanding. But I am not sure still its good design in new age of Spring 5.x.

Comment: This is not just spring specific. It is highly recommended to interact through interfaces instead of concrete implementation. The benefit is if suppose in future you want to create new implementation then you can easily switch to it without doing any change in client code. Client code means where you are using that interface. Its basically the concept of abstraction among OOPs principles.